# Circumflex and sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, circumflex-orm

Has anyone successfully used [Circumflex ORM](http://circumflex.ru/projects/orm/index.html) from an sbt project?  How can I specify my Circumflex properties, such as 'orm.connection.driver'?  A properties.cx file is not picked up as my runtime classpath apparently contains only sbt-launch-0.7.3.jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you placing the properties.cx file? Assuming Circumflex is using normal classpath loading, it should probably go in src/main/resources. I have not used Circumflex, so perhaps it is doing something odd, but that would be the typical location for properties in an SBT project.

Comment: It's picking up the property when I put it in src/main/resources.  Thanks!